# Editing Contact form in Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify

I want to add an image in the contact form on shopify 
I want this particular image to float on the left then the contact form appear on its right side 
Should i use 'Edit HTML/CSS 3' 
If so, which code should I key in so that the image can float left of the contact form

Answer (score 0):

- To edit the contact form:

  After clicking **Edit HTML/CSS**, go to the directory `template`, and edit the file `page.contact.liquid`
- To add it somewhere on your site:

  ```
   {% include 'page.contact' %}
  ```